# In Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc: Prevent _context from using cached results when initializing model

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

A table in my database is used to store a hierarchy. It does this by having a column represent it's parent, which is a foreign key to another row in the same table.

Another feature in this table is a column referencing a Branch.

A branch has permission to view all entries related to this entry (parent or children just not laterally).

To do this I will get all entities related to the branch and then recursively retrieve their children until I have a list of entities that don't have any children. At this point I was hoping to use 'OnModelCreating' method of DBContext to retrieve an daisy chain of objects until it reaches the top level.

This works partially. Everything works until I get to the `OnModelCreating` method where it retrieves parent objects until it gets to the parent object with the BranchId.

My assumption is that it uses a cached result from the line `marketsUnknownChildren = await _context.Markets.Where(x => x.BranchID.Equals(brancheID)).ToListAsync();`. Because the parent object has 'BranchID' set to 'null' the 'OnModelCreating' method does not find any object and leaves the parameter 'ParentMarket' as 'null'.

I've tested this by assigning various levels of the hierarchy to a branch. Each time It returns all entries which have no children and a chain of parent objects until the level that contains the branch.

How do I either:

Reload the objects with parentIds but no parentObject

or prevent the where clause from applying to the parent object

or not caching the results of the first query?

Thank you.

## Market

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TenantToolVmApi.Models
{
    [Table("Markets")]
    public class Market
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("Branch ID")]
        public int? BranchID { get; set; }

        [Column("ParentId")]
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public virtual Market? ParentMarket { get; set; }

        [Column("Canada_Plus_MarketsID")]
        public int Canada_Plus_MarketsID {get; set;}

        [Column ("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## MarketContext

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TenantToolVmApi.Models
{
    public class MarketContext : DbContext
    {
        public MarketContext(DbContextOptions<MarketContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Market> Markets { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Market>()
                .HasOne(u => u.ParentMarket);
        }
    }
}
```

## MarketCotroller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TenantToolVmApi.Models;

namespace TenantToolVmApi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class MarketsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MarketContext _context;

        public MarketsController(MarketContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Markets
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Market>>> GetMarketsItems()
        {
            string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            PermissionController permissionController = new PermissionController(userName);
            if (permissionController.HasNationalScope())
                return await _context.Markets.ToListAsync();
            else
            {
                int brancheID = permissionController.GetAccessibleBranches();

                IEnumerable<Market> marketsHasNoChildren = new List<Market>();
                List<int> addedIds = new List<int>();
                IEnumerable<Market> marketsUnknownChildren;
                IEnumerable<Market> marketsToCheckOnNextPass;
                IEnumerable<Market> result;


                marketsUnknownChildren = await _context.Markets.Where(x => x.BranchID.Equals(brancheID)).ToListAsync();

                while (marketsUnknownChildren.Count() > 0)
                {
                    marketsToCheckOnNextPass = new List<Market>();
                    foreach (Market market in marketsUnknownChildren)
                    {
                        result = await _context.Markets.Where(x => x.ParentId.Equals(market.ID)).ToListAsync();
                        if (result.Count() > 0)
                            marketsToCheckOnNextPass = marketsToCheckOnNextPass.Concat(result);
                        else if (!addedIds.Contains(market.ID))
                        {
                            marketsHasNoChildren = marketsHasNoChildren.Concat(new List<Market> { market });
                            addedIds.Add(market.ID);
                        }
                    }
                    marketsUnknownChildren = marketsToCheckOnNextPass;
                }

                ActionResult<IEnumerable<Market>> returnActionResults = marketsHasNoChildren.ToList();
                return returnActionResults;
            }
        }

        private bool MarketsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Markets.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your model design , it seems that there is a self-referencing one-to-one relationship in `Market`. And `?` operator is used after a non-nullable simple type , not complex type. Refer to the below code:

```
[Table("Markets")]
public class Market
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("Branch ID")]
    public int? BranchID { get; set; }

    [Column("ParentId")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Market ParentMarket { get; set; }

    [Column("Canada_Plus_MarketsID")]
    public int Canada_Plus_MarketsID { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Market>()
            .HasOne(u => u.ParentMarket)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Market>(u => u.ParentId)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

And then you can use [`Include()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) method to load the related data

```
await _context.Markets.Include(m=>m.ParentMarket).Where(x => x.BranchID.Equals(brancheID)).ToListAsync();
```

Result

[image]